# Django for TCP/IP and Websockets connections

Tags: django, tornado

I am building a trading back-end that provides live streaming prices (over Websockets) and trading functionality (REST endpoints) to the web client. The back-end was planned to be build with Django. However, the back-end also needs to receive live prices over TCP/IP connection from the 3rd party server and further distribute prices over Websockets to end-users.

Django is powerful and has lots of built-in features out-of-the-box including REST framework, admin panel, ORM, etc.

However, how I start a TCP connection and distribute price feed over Websockets? Can I use a management command to start a new thread?

Should I rather look into a different frameworks like Tornado? Tornado is apparently good for non-blocking network I/O and Websockets. However, it's a complex thing with a lot of state.
If I could, I'd rather stick with Django. What would you suggest?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/?

Comment: @AKX I have seen it but I still need to start external TCP/IP connection to get prices from the server and instantly share prices with all existing websocket connections.

Comment: I'd probably set up a separate process to work with the price server (since it's not request-response -oriented) that e.g. uses redis pubsub to publish new data to be distributed to the clients.